# Excel 2015, freezing a cell's figure when conditions are met

Tags: excel

I'm using Excel 2015. When the figure in a cell reaches or goes over a limit, I would want that cell to lock/freese, so that when I come back to it I can still see that the limit was reached.

The problem is that it's a live chart and the figure can go back down below the limit, knocking of the indicator that tells me the limit was reached. I can set a warning/indicator for when a limit is reached but can't work out how to freeze the limit being reached. This freezing can be in the cell beside if needs be.

Comment: Hi, well I could not wait until this evening. I just had to give it a go straight away, hehe. It works a treat. Thanks again. If was wanted to apply this to a list of different independant figures. Is there a way to drag it into the other cells or is it a case of repeating the code for each independant figure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this using standard functions, but you could use a [User Defined Function](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/user-defined-function.html) for this:

On the 'Developer' tab, select 'View Code' to, well, view the code for the workbook - this opens the Visual Basic editor.

Select `Insert` -> `Module`, and you should see a 'Modules' branch appear in the tree, expand this and double-click on `Module1` (that you just inserted).

Add the following code

```
Public Curmax(10) As Double
Public Reset As Boolean
```

---

```
Function RunMax(Cell As Range, maxref As Integer) As Double
    Application.Volatile (True) 'Ensures UDF is run when the sheet recalculates
    If Cell.Value > Curmax(maxref) Then
        Curmax(maxref) = Cell.Value
    End If
    RunMax = Curmax(maxref)
End Function
```

---

```
Sub ClearRunMax()
    With ActiveCell
        maxref = Mid(.Formula, InStr(.Formula, ",") + 1, 1)
        Curmax(maxref) = 0
        ActiveSheet.Calculate
    End With
End Sub
```

Now if you enter `=RunMax(A1,1)` in a cell, it will keep a running maximum of what was in  cell `A1` as maximum reference no. `1`, to add another, then just  increase the reference - `=RunMax(C3,2), =RunMax(F56,3)`, up to a maximum of 10 (or whatever you put in `Public Curmax(10) As Double`)

If you place a button on the page, assigning the `ClearRunMax` macro to it, it will reset the maximum  to the current value of the cell you are tracking (assuming it is >0) if you select a call containing the `RunMax` statement and then click the button.

This could be improved, I will be the first to admit. There is no error checking for example. So of you have the wrong cell selected when you press the button, you'll get a `Type Mismatch`. Also, if your values are negative, the reset won't work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try this this evening and let you know how it went.

Comment: Sorry I posted a reply in the wrong comment section. It should have been here. Please read from above.

Comment: Hi @Eamonn, if my answer helped you, it is customary to mark the answer as 'accepted'. As far as dragging into other cells is concerned, no, that won't work, that's one of it's limitations. You would need another public variable for each cell, and some way of choosing which one to update, in the function. that shouldn't be too hard though.

Comment: Hi @SiHa. I will accept your answer for sure. If you ever have any Furniture Design/Making questions don't hesitate to ask. Is it possible to post how to do what you've suggest in regards to doing this with multiple independant figures?

Comment: @Eamonn: See edited answer, this allows up to 10 independent maxima to be tracked.

Comment: Thanks again. For now I will get used to doing it for each one on it's own. Then later when I've becomed accustomed to what I'm doing I will progress to the multiple formula. I don't want to run before I can walk. In a few days I will post back if I've any problems. Thanks you very much.